# How to create a survey list in SharePoint which accepts limited responses?

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to create a survey list in SharePoint which accepts a limited number of responses. Suppose, if 1000 persons submitted their responses, then the next , i.e. 1001 th person should get a message "The maximum limit reached. Your responses cannot be submitted right now.". Can anybody please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would still want that information even if the user submitted after the first 1000.  I would still pull down a report for the first 1000 responses but then you still have access to the extra data if need be.  If its a requirement to cap the list at 1000 see this article (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136244/max-number-of-items-in-a-sharepoint-list)